# ¿"Mil nueve" para indicar el año 1900?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, hispanoamérica, tiempo, argentina, números

Estaba ayer viendo una película argentina ("Nueve Reinas", del año 2000, por si eso condiciona de alguna forma) cuando observé una forma diferente de llamar los años:

- Para decir el año 1920 decían "mil nueve veinte".
- De la misma forma, el año 1990 lo dirían "mil nueve noventa", etc.

Es decir, en lugar de "mil novecientos..." decían "mil nueve".

¿Qué tan común es esta expresión en Argentina? [Rodrigo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/6915/rodrigo) comenta que también se usa en Chile y oigo a [un político de Bolivia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0mPTnNrovU) que también lo usa. ¿Se usa en otras zonas de América del Sur? ¿Es normativa?

Comment: En Chile es lo más habitual en la norma informal, independiente del estrato. El Combate Naval de Iquique fue en _mil ocho setenta y nueve_.

Comment: @Rodrigo esto es muy interesante, no tenía ni idea de que se utilizara esta forma. Y de hecho, me parece utilísima, cercana al inglés "diecinueve" y mucho mejor que el largo "mil novecientos...".

Comment: Si mil nueve significa 1900 cómo dicen 1900?

Comment: Por contexto. Por ejemplo si un kilo de pan vale "mil dos" todos entendemos que vale $1.200 y no $1.002, porque en Chile los precios se redondean a la decena. A veces es ambiguo y hay que aclarar. Pero nadie se equivoca en entender "mil nueve veinticuatro", sobre todo con precios y fechas.

Comment: Estoy comentando en vez de responder porque la pregunta se refiere a Argentina y yo soy chileno. Por cierto, nunca me imaginé que esto fuera un regionalismo. Estamos tan acostumbrados que sentimos que es la forma universal de decirlo.

Comment: @Rodrigo bueno de hecho al verlo en una película Argentina asumí que era propio de ese país únicamente. Como veo que no es el caso, edito para hacerlo más genérico... y así poder tener una respuesta tuya : )

Comment: No se usa en Colombia. Aquí normalmente usamos la forma larga (novecientos), claro que con tantos canales de cable operados desde más al sur, es muy posible que en unos años también lo estemos usando.

Comment: Creo que los comentarios de @Rodrigo serían la respuesta a esta pregunta y deberían ponerse como tal.

Comment: @Jaime En Argentina, según mi experiencia, _1900_ se diría "mil novecientos", nunca escuché que se dijese "mil nueve": esa forma se usa cuando hay más cifras a continuación, como en los ejemplos mencionados o en los que señala Rodrigo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En Chile es muy frecuente acortar los números largos, sobre todo quitando el sufijo de las centenas. Es una costumbre arraigada que se da en situaciones informales y que no implica en absoluto un bajo nivel cultural.

Por ejemplo, en el habla cotidiana el número 1.340 se puede decir de cualquiera de estas formas:

> mil trescientos cuarenta
>
> mil tres cuarenta

aunque en situaciones formales se usa sólo la primera.

Dos excepciones son *ciento* y *quinientos*, que nunca se eliminan (por ejemplo 1540 siempre es *mil quinientos cuarenta*, nunca *mil cinco cuarenta*).

En [este video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DaKuMz2pXHo) se puede escuchar un ejemplo en la televisión. El primer locutor dice "ocho noventa y cinco" y el segundo dice "ochocientos noventa y cinco". El ejemplo es bueno porque el primer hablante usa las dos formas en una misma cifra y no genera confusión.

A veces se presentan formas ambiguas, que deben ser aclaradas por el hablante, dándose situaciones un poco confusas. Por ejemplo:

> -Hay que hacer los ejercicios de la página mil dos.
>
> -¿Mil doscientos?
>
> -No. Mil dos.

Con respecto a las unidades de mil, se da sólo un caso de acortamiento, cuando el resto de la cifra es 500. Por ejemplo el número 3.500 se puede decir en situaciones informales de cualquiera de estas dos formas:

> tres mil quinientos
>
> tres quinientos

Comment: Al leer las palabras _tres quinientos_ me hizo recordar que hace algunos años, había escuchado a algunas personas usar estas palabras cuando iba al comprar algo y recibía el _cambio_ o las _vueltas_ (usado únicamente para las unidades de mil); sin embargo, solo puedo decir que era algo esporádico y dependía de las personas.

Answer (score 4):

En argentina lo usamos para las fechas unicamente. Si de plata se refiera si decis mil nueve estan diciendo 1009. Y si decís mil nueve veinte se esta diciendo 1920, al igual si decis mil novecientos veinte, pero la primera forma no es utilizada habitualmente.