# How do I refer to a room number in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, números, chile

In English, when I refer to, say, room 328 in a building, I say "three twenty eight" and not "three hundred twenty eight" because the digit 3, referring to the floor, is in some sense separated from the 28. Does the same pattern hold in Spanish? Should I say *habitación trescientos veintiocho*, or *habitación tres ventiocho*, or something else?

Follow up question: What if I am talking about room 308?

Comment: I would say the complete number: "trescientos veintiocho" and "trescientos ocho", but this question may have regional differences. Are you interested in the answers to be centered in the European Spanish or in the American Spanish?

Comment: I have added the Chile tag, as that is the dialect I am most interested in.

Comment: Perfect, I must then say that my comment applies in Spain. Let's see what our Chilean members have to say about this. And welcome to [Spanish.SE]!

Comment: Regarding the use of long numbers in Chile, this answer is related.: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/15450/6915

Comment: That is interesting because I would say it is room three two eight but perhaps that is a dialectal difference. I use the dialect of the south eastern corner of England. And I would say three oh eight for your second example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have heard the first form more than the second. But certainly both are used (at least in Latin America).

For your examples it would be:

> "Habitación trescientos veintiocho"

&

> "Habitación trescientos ocho"

Comment: Estoy deacuerdo contigo. Es mas por comodidad que por regla gramatical.

Comment: I would use "Habitación tres veintiocho" and people will totally understand it, but I think the proper way to say it is "Habitación trescientos veintiocho" as mentioned in this answer.